# difference "on" and "emmit" in server and client in socket.io

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I have a hard time understanding when server "send" the data and when client "get" the data and vice versa.

The code is in their example

in `index.js` for nodejs

```
// server side
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

io.on('connection', function(socket){
  console.log('a user connected');

  // create chat message
  socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
    io.emit('chat message', msg);
    console.log('message: ' + msg);
  });

  socket.on('disconnect', function(){
    console.log('user disconnected');
  });
});

http.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

and in the script

```
$( function(){
  'use strict';
  // client side
  console.log("starting chat...");
  var socket = io();


  $('form').submit(function(){
    // call event chat message
    socket.emit('chat message', $('#m').val());
    $('#m').val('');
    return false;
  });

  // create chat message event on client
  socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
    $('#messages').append($('<li>').text(msg));
  })
});
```

as you can see on `index.js` it create a `chat message` and using io it `emmit` it. The same thing is on in the script. So the question is how does the server and client "talk" with each other? and what it is the different between `emmit` and `on` ?

Comment: `emit` sends a message, `on` receives an event, isn't that obvious?

Comment: Do you know how servers and clients work in general, and what a socket is?

Comment: i do (server and client), but not so in socket,  I don't understand how they talk, as you can see they both using event "new message", how come they don't conflict with each other?

Comment: It's symmetric. Messages the clients sends are received on the server, messages the server sends are received on the client. They don't conflict because they have a direction.

Comment: so is like POST or GET then the server render the result ? but happening on the same time?

Comment: Yes, it's like the difference between a HTTP request and a HTTP response. Only that HTTP can only send one thing and then tears down the connection, while web *sockets* as used by socket.io stay open so that they can transport multiple messages.

Comment: ah that explain a lot thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever we are using socket io , we use **emit** to send server a message with given message identifier and server now replies client by emitting a message with some message identifier say **x**, then we use that **on** method and pass **x** identifier and grab the message from server.